# How to upload Selected Photo from Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, file-upload

I am trying to develop an app for Windows Phone in C# which basically uploads a user selected picture to a server (localhost, for example).
This app is meant to work just like a PHP file upload script, where user chooses a file and then it is uploaded to a desired directory on the server.

I've already written the code for selecting the picture with the help of Picture Chooser task.
But, now I'm completely confused. I just don't know what to do with the selected picture.

This is the code for the page which asks user to select a picture:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;


namespace QR_Reader
{
    public partial class SamplePage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public SamplePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        PhotoChooserTask selectphoto = null;

        private void SampleBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            selectphoto = new PhotoChooserTask();
            selectphoto.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(selectphoto_Completed);
            selectphoto.Show();
        }

        void selectphoto_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {

                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(e.ChosenPhoto);
                image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(e.OriginalFileName));
                txtBX.Text = e.OriginalFileName;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Please help me.

Here, txtBX is a textbox to display the path of the selected picture.

Comment: "I just don't know what to do with the selected picture." - presumably you need to write some upload code...

Comment: Yeah, exactly! But I don't have any idea from where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

What service are you planning on uploading the picture, that is the question. **[Here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/building-imgur-client-windows-3)** is an extensive guide on how to upload it to Imgur.

Generic uploads can go like this:

```
string uploadUrl = "http://uploadserver/upload.php";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uploadUrl);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; 
request.BeginGetRequestStream((result) =>
{
    using (Stream stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(result))
    {
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); // your binary data
    }

    request.BeginGetResponse((rResult) => 
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(rResult);

        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
              // Do something here.
        }
    }
}, null);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.
Actually, I want to upload it to my server; just like I would in HTML upload form.

In other words, simulation of a multipart file upload form in C# is what I need. I've tried a lot, but I could not figure how to do it.

Please help me.

Comment: Your server needs to have an endpoint to be able to upload there. It's not a matter of "Here's a file from my phone, store it somehow." Does your server have one?

Comment: See, I am able to upload pictures to my server with the help of PHP file upload.

I just want to do the exact same thing, but with an application on the phone. That's it.

Comment: Well, yeah, any one can access a web page (or a file) stored on the server if he/she has the URL.

Comment: What I meant is - do you have a public endpoint that we can test on? But anyway, check the edited post.

Comment: Thank you very much.

I think this will lead to the right path.

But, I have a question: how will upload.php handle the upload from C# client.
Can you please give a complete example to upload the picture to upload.php (along with PHP & C# code). That would be very helpful.

Yes, I know I might be bugging you a lot. But, seriously I need help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

```
static private async Task<JToken> 
           ImageUploadApiCallAsync(string strApiName, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameterList, Stream imageStream, string strFileName)
        {
            JToken token = null;

            if (!CheckConnection())
            {
                token = @"{
                                'success':false,
                                'message':'No connection',
                                'errorcode':1
                                }";
                return token;
            }

            try
            {
                //Get your api URL
                string strRequestUri = getApiUrlWithApiName(strApiName);

                var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());

                using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                {
                    //I did a stream compression here since I don't want the original size image to upload to my server to reduce space and internet flow.
                    Stream uploadStream = SystemUtil.CompressImageStream(imageStream);

                    content.Add(new StreamContent(uploadStream), "file", strFileName);

                    //Add my api parameters into content
                    foreach (var keyValuePair in parameterList)
                    {
                        content.Add(new StringContent(keyValuePair.Value), keyValuePair.Key);
                    }
                    //Do PostAsync
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(strRequestUri, content);
                    HttpResponseMessage message = response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    //Get result from server
                    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    token = JObject.Parse(responseString);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                token = @"{
                                'success':false,'message':'" + e.Message + "','errorcode':2}";
            }
            return token;
        }
```